# How to view JDK external documentation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, javadoc

The shortcut for this action is Shift+F1 but it is always grayed out even though I have pointed JDK `documentation path` to the `docs` folder (the docs folder is unzipped from [jdk-7u2-apidocs.zip](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/java-se-7-doc-download-435117.html) ).
Thanks

Answer (score 107, accepted):

You need to specify the `docs/api` subdirectory of the unpacked documentation or use `https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/` URL for the external documentation feature to work.

`File -> Project Structure...` then here :
[image]

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Additionally, is there a way to make it display documentation in HTML format ?

Comment: What do you mean? It just opens the HTML page in the default browser.

Comment: Sorry for confusing. I asked if I can make it display in HTML format in the documentation window in IntelliaJ IDEA (Ctrl+Q) for quick view purpose.

Comment: Ctrl+Q is rendered either from the source javadoc or from the HTML documentation, it's the same documentation as you see in the HTML format.

Comment: It misses some images and rich formats compared to HTML in browser.

Comment: Where do I need to add the http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/  path for this feature to work?

Comment: Link should now be [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/) (note the 'https' and the '8'). I tried to edit but SO won't let me change just two characters :/

Comment: I'm looking for the location where OpenJdk has it's javadocs locally. I don't have access on the developer system to reach out to any http:// path. Where would I find the javadocs located?

Comment: @Elijah JavaDoc is not a part of the JDK, you need to download/unpack them manually.

Answer (score 16):

I'm using 10.5.4. It was unclear to me from the docs or from resources online that you need to add this at Project Structure > SDK's > (Choose your SDK) > Documentation Paths > Specify URL.

Answer (score 6):

You can add the external Javadocs API link as shown below:

- Go to `File` > `Project Structure...`
- Then select `SDKs` (under `Platform Settings`)
- Go to `Documentation Paths` tab
- Select `Specify URL` button and add the link for JDK 11 API docs (https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/)

[image]

Answer (score 5):

For IntelliJ Idea:
Call "Project Structure" (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+S), go to "Platform Setting - SDKs", choose "Documentation Path" tab on the right, then add url of JavaDoc (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/) to your project

Answer (score 3):

Posting this here in case you're like me and don't necessarily want javadocs, but rather the documentation inside your IDE.

In my situation, I had downloaded OpenJDK 11 and wasn't able to get documentation inside IntelliJ. Instead I was getting decompiled code.

What helped me was the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/38413439
i.e.

1. Go to File > Project Structure > SDKs > Sourcepath > '+' on the right side.
2. Navigate to your JDK (I'm on Ubuntu so it was located under `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/`).
3. Select the `src.zip` (for me, `/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-11/lib/src.zip`).
4. Click OK > OK (to "Choose Roots" pop-up) > OK (to Project Structure)

Let Intellij index and it should be available in your IDE.

Answer (score 2):

I understand the question as follows:

You would like to see javadocs of classes that are not within JDK. I am a bit uncertain because CrazyCoder's reply is talking about JDK specific javadocs.

```
I am using Macos 10.8.4 and Intellij 11.1.5
```

The project I am working on is a mvn based project with many modules which have complex dependencies.

Let me take a concrete example to explain what I did, I am sure it can be reproduced for others: apache sshd

I downloaded the javadoc from maven central stored it stored it somewhere. In intellij I went to the module settings (shortcut F4) and the to Libraries in the sidebar. Maven pulls all dependencies automagically and I can find sshd there. The right side then shows Classes, Sources and JavaDocs. The JavaDocs part in my case had a path linked in that pointed to my local m2 directory. However the directory did not contain the javadoc jar file. So I thought how do I get it:

```
mvn dependency:resolve -Dclassifier=javadoc
```

[Taken from here](http://piotrga.wordpress.com/2009/06/25/how-to-download-javadocs-or-sources-in-maven-2/)

However this failed for because we do not have some javadocs in our nexus (I guess, not sure).

So I ended up linking the file that I downloaded manually in as a javadoc link and this then allown me to use Shift+F1 for the javadoc to open in my standard browser.

Maybe others can elaborate on how to get this done with mvn. I did not have the time to further investigate.

Answer (score 1):

Java 10 Documentation path

Got to File -> Project Structure Choose External URL

Below Link works Fine... THe default one does'nt work

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/

Answer (score 0):

Other answers are satisfying but in case you still can't see the documentation, make sure that your java file is located under the `src` path.

Answer (score 0):

Adding online URL as documentation introduces a delay for the documentation to pop up. I prefer linking my sources from local for zero lag.

You should be able to find the `src.zip` in `jdk/lib/src.zip` path. Add that archive in your documentation paths and you're all set.

If using some other JDK, you could grab the sources separately. Or might come bundled.

[image: Intellij JDK javadocs setup]