# How do I find dowloadable API documentation for JDK 8?

Tags: java

I just spent 30 minutes trying to find the downloadable Java API documentation, and could not find documentation for my installed version, 1.8_20, only 1.8_31. I am using a Mac. Under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/` there is no `docs/api` subdirectory, as claimed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8589892/2596664). After I downloaded 1.8_31, I tried to figure out the "right way" to get the API documentation, but I don't see a way to download it on this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/ . The `Java SE API Documentation` link takes me to the online API documentation, and I don't see a way to download it. What am I missing?

Comment: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html

Like this?

Comment: Yes, like that. As I said, I found it for 1.8_31, after much digging. Where is the documentation for 1.8_20? Where is a link to get to that page? Do I have to extract the documentation into `docs/api`? Why isn't it there to begin with?

Comment: They will be almost identical, unless you find a change listed [here](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/release_changes.xml) which affects you.

Comment: Is there a link or path of links to http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/jdk8-doc-downloads-2133158.html from the JDK installation page, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html ?

Comment: You can't download it without accepting the license, and there isn't a link to the license. I think you might have better luck getting the source to openjdk 8u20 and building the javadoc yourself.