# How to view Guava external documentation in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm able to setup the Java standards library documentation within IntelliJ using the instructions here:
[How to view JDK external documentation in IntelliJ IDEA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587522/how-to-view-jdk-external-documentation-in-intellij-idea)

But following the same process I cannot get the documentation to work for Google's Guava.  The documentation url for the google project is:
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/overview-summary.html

But using that with IntelliJ doesn't load the documentation when I view a Guava class.  Do I need to use a different url for the guava documentation?

Comment: Did you try `https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/` URL? Or you can attach the sources to the library and Quick Documentation will work using the sources.

Comment: Sadly I've tried that URL and also downloading the sources and docs and neither are resolving when I try to view quick documentation on a Guava class.

Comment: Please share the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to reproduce.